# Point position on Map not fixed- Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a project which allows a User to place and name a point on a map. The problem is that after the point has been placed, if the user zooms out, the point moves with the map. I have a couple of screenshots to illustrate the problem.

[1: After point has been placed](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/6/pointplaced.png)

[2: Zoomed out](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/29/zoomedout.png)

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems just to be that icon, tried another and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the appropriate anchor for your custom icon (probably should be the point of the pin).

Comment: Oh okay.. do you know how to go about setting it??

Comment: Yes.  But, you haven't provided any of your code that defines your custom marker or a link to your custom marker.  With just pictures, it is impossible to suggest a fix that would be useful to you.  I can point you to the [Google Maps API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays), but you should be able to find that yourself, and it isn't clear that you are using that.